# Where do I write code in my minecraft modding environment?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

So this is probably a stupid question but I'm just beginning so I hope someone can help. I set up my whole modding environment in eclipse but the problem is that I don't know where to start writing code that will be run while playing the game. I'm used to there being a run method that will constantly loop and run the code within that method but there doesn't seem to be such a thing. I tried putting stuff in my main class under the init event handler but that just crashed my game. I was just testing stuff out and tried putting this code in the init area which caused the game to crash when I tried running the client:

```
Entity player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;
if(player.posX>100.0)
{
 player.posX = 12.0;
}
```